# Asking for IT equipment in first couple weeks of new job?

Tags: developer, software-development

I'm starting a new development job in a week or so, and when I was there to under-go code testing, I was shown what would be my desk. I noticed it only had two monitors, both 19 inches. This, for a developer, is very little screen space and can be quite a pain to work with.

How unprofessional would it be of me to ask for a new set of monitors within the first few weeks? It'll greatly increase my efficiency, so it'd definitely be worth it. I'll also be the first in-house developer at this place, so would it be wrong of me to ask for paid-for software. I develop in ASP.NET and use Visual Studio 2015, however there are licensing laws against a large company using the free version.

I don't want to go in asking for this, that, etc, but a lot of it will increase productivity/make my job 100x easier.

Comment: `I noticed it only had two monitors, both 19 inches. This, for a developer, is very little screen space`. Kids these days... :-D

Comment: If you are the "first in-house developer" does that mean that the company has had contract developers previously?  Or that they have never had developers working in the office?  If years of consultants have managed to develop on 2 19" monitors with whatever software the company has licensed, asking to come in and immediately change things would potentially be problematic.  Ideally, this sort of thing should have been something that you discussed during the interview process.

Comment: Only 2 19 inch monitors? I'm working on a contract at a very large telecom helping to build an app that processes literally billions of dollars in invoices. I'm working on a laptop with a 15" screen. In my considered opinion, you're being a prima donna or diva. ONE screen is a pain, but workable. 2 is sufficient. 3 is a luxury You'll survive. It will only significantly increase your efficiency if you're unwilling to adapt to what the rest of us mere mortals work with.

Comment: Have they already told you what software they're expecting you to use?

Comment: @BSMP I would assume the code test would be in the language he is supposed to Programm in otherwise why test at all?

Comment: @RaoulMensink - OK, I had a brain fart. Still, it's unclear to me whether he's being asked to use the free version and feels uneasy about it or if he feels like he'll have to use the free version behind their backs because they don't have VS at all.

Comment: @BSMP I think the op Needs to do his first week of work before he or we can answer that. I think he is assuming that seeing as he is the first inhouse developer that they dont have anything for him. Which might be true, but a big Company is more likely to have thought about the Overall expenses of hireing someone before they even open the spot.

Comment: Please clear up if the company currently has the free version installed?

Comment: james, is this your first development job?

Comment: Tastes differ, of course, but I've usually found two monitors to be something of a PITA for work.  A single 24" or larger display (with at least 1920x1200 resolution) and multiple virtual screens is much easier to work with.

Comment: I don't understand the negativity towards the Idea of having 3 monitors. Asking for rose pedals in the water cooler is being a diva, asking for work equipment that costs a fraction of the personal costs is not - even if this configuration is uncommon. For instance in my organization it was considered an unnecessary luxury to include an SSD, long after I bought one for my personal PC. I still use a private mechanical keyboard. Denying developers work equipment that they personally afford for their hobby is stupid.

Comment: @ChrisE It depends. Better equipment definitely help in being more productive. There are also researches that proves it. A lot of experienced developers including you are fine with 1, but it doesn't make it true for everyone. In the end, company benefits from higher productivity of developers. https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-programmers-bill-of-rights/

Comment: @Zulan Exactly. They are so cheap. Even my home workstation is more advanced than work. We are asking for work related stuff not a BMW. Moreover the most annoying part is this stuff is never going to get away. Monitors will stay at company and usually last very very long too. They can be used by future developers too.

Answer (score 13):

There are many aspects to this request that you need to be aware of.

For example, what sort of screens is everyone else using? If people who've been there for 5+ years are *also* using 19" screens, and you come along asking for larger ones, then you're practically guaranteed not to get them.

If, however, you're the only one who has small screens, then *perhaps* they will buy you new ones. Remember, however, that you're not even past your probation, so your request isn't likely going to carry much weight.

Furthermore, the fact that they're not bothering to buy professional software should be a ***big*** warning sign to you that these people are not prioritizing your needs or wants as a developer. (if this is because they just don't understand the difference yet, they you should explain it to them ASAP)

At the end of the day, if you do decide to request new screens, be very polite and respectful. Ask to meet with your manager/supervisor, and express your opinion. If you can find some sort of study recommending screens of a certain size for development purposes (is there such a thing?) then you can maybe show it to management at that time.

---

**An aside based on personal experience:**

I've worked a co-op in circumstances very similar to what you're describing. I was the only developer in a small company where I was expected to program in the free edition of Visual Basic, and my desk was a folding table.

My advice to you is to get some decent experience (finish a project or two for them), and then ***bounce as soon as you can*** (after a year or two at the most).

In this sort of environment you won't have anyone else mentoring, or guiding your growth as a programmer, and it's very easy to stagnate, or pick up bad habits. These people are probably not used to working with developers, and will not understand why you might need to take your time setting up the foundation for a piece of software, taking your time to design something before implementing it, etc. (and no one will be around to teach you how to do it properly either)

These sort of places are usually characterized by a constant pressure to get something on screen, in order to demonstrate progress to managers who don't know the first thing about development, and think it's synonymous with IT support.

Comment: Your second paragraph has some good meaning behind it. I've been working IT at a company for 5 months now, and I still have a tiny, slow Macbook Air. It's just not my time to ask for something better yet, and it does what I need it to anyway.

Comment: `and my desk was a folding table`  I had to laugh at that.  Working onsite in the manufacturing industry having a desk of *any* sort can be luxury.  And that's not even talking about chairs - which can range from none to wooden crate totrash can to metal folding chair (if you are lucky)

Comment: @PeterM Really? A dev without desk or chair ? They must don't care at all for your job.

Comment: Where do you get they are not using licensed software?

Comment: @paparazzi - the OP specifies that they are using the free version of VS 2015 to develop. Any software written with the purpose of making money (business applications, for example) require that you buy the license - to my knowledge. A company _should_ acquire a VS license in order to avoid any legal unpleasantness down the line.

Comment: He did not say they OP said I.  OP stated HE is using the free version and is starting in a week or two.  No evidence the company is using unlicensed software.

Comment: @paparazzi - **"would it be wrong of me to ask for paid-for software"** <- my understanding of that sentence is that they're using the free VS version.

Comment: He is the first developer.   Why would they be using a development tool now?   Asking for paid-for software does not imply they are using pirated.  He just does not want to install unlicensed software.

Comment: @paparazzi - I never said "pirated". I've worked for a bunch of companies, however, who use the free version of various software because they don't understand the risk, or don't prioritize the dev team (1 developer in a manufacturing business scenario). My argument is that a company not willing to pay for the right tools is not a company worth working for. Anyway, we're kinda beating a dead horse.

Comment: Again there is not specific evidence they are using free / pirated at this time.

Comment: @AndreiROM VS 2015 Community edition is free for specific scenarios (open source, education, small teams (non-enterprise, <= 5 developers)). It is a full version of the tool and should be fine to use as the primary development environment, assuming his employer qualifies to use it. VS Express is completely free for anyone to use, but is crippled in some ways that make it less efficient for professional development work. OP would definitely be within reason to request an upgrade from the Express version.

Comment: @Carlos2W When you're 300 feet up in a crane or sitting in a control room that still doesn't have walls you take what you can get.  That is the environment you play in when you build things in the manufacturing industry, and everybody involved understands that.  That's not to say I don't prefer a nice desk and chair..

Comment: +1 for the aside. It was awful for my personal development being the only dev at my first dev job.

Answer (score 6):

AndreiROM's answer is excellent and to the point, but I'd like to give you another perspective : if you are programming GUI, and if *your users have far worse screens than you have*(not unlikely, unfortunately), then your screens are already a danger for being too nice.

Our GUI developpers have very big screens, the best money can buy. Some of our customers often have 10-years old crappy machines, with 13" screens, 15" when they are lucky. And they suffer from having scrollbars everywhere on their screens, which makes some of important features very tough to use. When the developper does not feel the pain of the end-user, he might program it happily, without realizing he's doing bad.

So it's a trade-off. Of course better stuff(not only screens, whatever) allows for better productivity. But if it makes you think that everythng is nice, while the result on end-users's machines will be catastrophic, then it's useless to be more productive.

Comment: Please tell your GUI developers to go back to School benches. if they dont even care about the main part of their Job: makeing the GUI useable for the **user (s)**. Then why do GUI development at all?

Comment: This. "Responsiveness" is a thing outside of the browser too. If they hardcode all sizes and positions in px etc., they are the worst possible kind of GUI developers

Comment: That's really odd developing software for others without taking into account their hardware's limitations.  Like building 25-foot-wide trucks for customers with 8-foot-wide roads.  Then, they're not customers, they're hostages.

Comment: @NoloProblemo Guess what? Many car manufacturers actually are like that.

Comment: At one place we had customers paying us lots of money who used an arrangement of six monitors (two rows of three monitors) so we had to buy that to be able to support them properly...

Comment: Akin to [dogfooding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food).

Answer (score 3):

> I'll also be the first in-house developer at this place, so would it
>   be wrong of me to ask for paid-for software. I develop in ASP.NET and
>   use Visual Studio 2015, however there are licensing laws against a
>   large company using the free version.

Now techically you are allowed to use it as free Software in small development Groups.
I have no idea how this works for larger company's IANAL.

You should **definitly** Point this out in a team/personal meeting or write an email.

> I noticed it only had two monitors, both 19 inches

Ask around what the Standard Office Equipment is you might be lucky to even have 2 Monitors.

Larger Company's with minimal/no IT personal are more likely not to have 2 "big" Screens. Reasoning could be to save Money as 18 Inch are probeply cheaper than 20-30inch.

I to would prefer to work with 2 big Monitors, but I would never fight for a bigger Monitor as I feel that doesnt make or break a workplace.

Also if your work has anything to do with web development or visual development for users with larger Screens you could Argument to get atleast one Screen of the biggest size available in the Company.

Comment: About your last paragraph, I asked for an iphone, because I was tasked to make an iOS app. They never bought me one. I still test on an emulator.

Comment: Uh, no, the Visual Studio Community Edition licensing is quite clear, if you are solely developing opensource applications, any number of developers in the business can use VS Community. If the business has less than 250 employees and has revenue that does not exceed $1Million in annual revenue, then 5 employees within that entire business can use VS Community for development of non-opensource applications.  If your business exceeds any of 250 PCs, $1Million in annual revenue or 5 active developers working on non-OSS, then you need to fork out for VS Pro at a minimum for *all* developers.

Comment: @Carlos2W: That's actually ridiculous, because there are things that you cannot test on the simulator. Like what happens if the user switches from WiFi to 3G. There are actually things that you cannot test unless you take your iPhone out of the office. How does your app behave when you are at Starbucks with a captive network? How does your app behave when you take your app on and off the underground?